# Include path from root

Tags: path, smarty

I have a structure kinda like this:

```
src
---stuff1
------stuff2
---------stuff3
------------tpl1.tpl
---dir1
------dir2
---------dir3
------------tpl2.tpl
```

I want to include the `tpl2.tpl` in `tpl1.tpl`, how can I avoid monsters like this: `{include file="../../../../../dir1/dir2/dir3/tpl.tpl"}`?

Comment: I would define a root path variable and use absolute paths, not relative paths

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example? I can't seem to find any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php file:

```
<?php
$root = "/path/to/the/root/of/my/site/or/templates"
$smarty->assign('root',$root);
```

template file:

```
{include file="`$root`/dir1/dir2/myfile.tpl"}
```

or

```
{include file="$root/dir1/dir2/myfile.tpl"}
```

or

```
{include file="$root|cat:"/dir1/dir2/myfile.tpl"}
```

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.quotes.tpl